# handling missing data with seasonality in python

Tags: python, missing-data, imputation, imputets

How can I use python to impute timeseries data with seasonality components?

Below is an example of how my data looks like, I am missing data for long periods that includes many cycles and not sure how to solve that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, is to have a look at [Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#python-api) - a Facebook package for time-series analysis. It does not impute data only, but it handles missing-data.

It breaks your data up in three functions; trend, seasonality and "holidays" ("holidays" you can treat as external feature e.g holidays, or days where you have campings, pay-check etc).

Answer (score 1):

The library FEDOT offers a powerful solution for this. Check the notebook:

https://github.com/nccr-itmo/FEDOT/blob/master/notebooks/latest/5_ts_specific_cases.ipynb

Snapshot from the example in the notebook:

[image]

Comment: The link is obsolete, the actual one is https://github.com/ITMO-NSS-team/fedot-examples/blob/main/notebooks/latest/5_ts_specific_cases.ipynb